# I can't get SharedPreferences to work

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I'm making an application for Android, on the Splash screen I would like it to show an AlertDialog the first time the application is launched. This is my code:

```
    SharedPreferences savedInfo = getSharedPreferences("SavedInfo", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor infoEditor = savedInfo.edit();

        boolean firstLaunch = savedInfo.getBoolean("firstLaunch", true);

        final AlertDialog importDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashActivity.this).create();

        if (firstLaunch == true) {
            importDialog.setTitle(R.string.splash_import_title);
            importDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.splash_import_text));
            importDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
            importDialog.setButton(getString(R.string.splash_import_yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //ALL FILE STUFF HERE
                    importDialog.dismiss();
                    startTimer();
                }
            });
            importDialog.setButton2(getString(R.string.splash_import_no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    importDialog.dismiss();
                        startTimer();
                }
            });  
            importDialog.show();
            infoEditor.putBoolean("firstLaunch", false);
        } else {
            startTimer();
        }
```

The problem is, it shows me the dialog everytime. Even when I have already launched it. Thanks for your time and help, zeokila.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to run `infoEditor.commit()` after `putBoolean`. It doesn't actually save the new preference until you do so.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell your editor to save.  add `infoEditor.commit();` (synchronous) OR `infoEditor.apply();` (async) to persist your value.

Answer (score 1):

`infoEditor.commit()` seems to be missing after `infoEditor.putBoolean("firstLaunch", false)`, so the new value is never been saved.